# How to toggle div using javascript keycodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle a div using keycodes. I've done it before but for some reason it's not working for me anymore. Can someone please help?

The HTML:

```
<div id="leftbottom" class="flex-container">
        <div id="chatcontainer" style="display:none; flex-direction:column">
            <div id="chatmessages">
            </div>

            <div id="chatenter" class="guielem guibutton">
                <div><img src="assets/chat-bubble.svg" style="width:20px; margin-left: 5px;margin-right:5px;"></div>
                <div>Press Enter to chat</div>
            </div>
            <div id="chatinputcontainer" class="guielem" style="display:none">
                <form id="chatinputform">
                    <input id="chatinput" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="message" maxlength="90">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

The div I want to be toggled:

```
<div id="chatcontainer" style="display:none; flex-direction:column">
```

What I have tried before (worked before but doesn't work now):

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (ws) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {

            // P
            case 80:
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('#chatContainer').toggle();
                break;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

The result I want to get is:

```
By default chatContainer is displayed
press P chatContainer is not displayed
press P chatContainer is displayed
press P chatContainer is not display
(Basically press P to show and hide the id)
```

Comment: First, replace `keyCode` with `key` because `keyCode` is depreciated.

Comment: What `if (ws)` suppose to mean?

Comment: @mini probably WebSockets for the chat

Comment: @Luca yes its websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your selectors. Replace:

```
<div id="chatcontainer" style="display:none; flex-direction:column">
```

with:

```
<div id="chatContainer" style="display:none; flex-direction:column">
```

`chatcontainer != chatContainer`

Comment: have you tried to remove `if (ws) {` - so you will know it is not related with web sockets

Answer (score 0):

please use css here
   declare the css first

```
<style>
.toggleDiv{
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

then update line in your javascript like this

```
$('#chatContainer').toggleClass('toggleDiv');
```